# hibernate with annotations in java, exception at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I'm creating a sample program with hibernate annotations. While running the program I'm getting the exception:

```
Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class
```

Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Stack Trace :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:800)
    at com.hibernate.tutorial.EmployeePersistor.main(EmployeePersistor.java:12)
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace please

Comment: ... and the annotated classes, which raise the exception.

Comment: Can you post `EmployeePersistor.java` and show us which is line `12`?

Comment: Line 12 - Session session = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();

Comment: Is there any issue with the jar versions? i am using hibernate3.

Comment: What version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: You are probably mixing incompatible versions of hibernate core and annotations.